# django rest auth returns AnonymousUser

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am using django, drf and django-rest-auth. I send token from frontend in request header

```
    {'Authorization': 'Token {$Token}'}
```

But this request seems like unauthorized. I want to get users information like:

```
    def get_user_info(request):
        user = request.user
```

but it returns me AnonymousUser

My settings.py:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'core',
        'rest_framework',
        'rest_framework.authtoken',
        'rest_auth',
        'account',
        'corsheaders'
    ]

    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
            'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'

        ),

        'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
            'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        ],
        'UNICODE_JSON': True,
        'PAGE_SIZE': 0
    }
```

That's my request headers:

```
    POST /auth/check/ HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:8000
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 0
    Pragma: no-cache
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Authorization: Token 7d2ee4481ea0e12bd88f46d57e2e6dab3354d4b7
    Origin: http://localhost:8080
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
    Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
    Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
    Referer: http://localhost:8080/
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

And full server response with headers

```
    HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
    Date: Thu, 29 Jun 2017 05:28:06 GMT
    Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.4.4
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
    Vary: Origin, Cookie
    Content-Type: application/json
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked

    {"message": "Unauthenticated"}
```

My view function:

```
    @csrf_exempt
    def check_auth(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print(request.user)
            if request.user.is_authenticated():
                content = {'message': 'Authenticated'}
                response = JsonResponse(content, status = 200)
                return response
            else:
                content = {'message': 'Unauthenticated'}
                response = JsonResponse(content, status=401)
                return response
```

Comment: What is the exact, full response of the server incl. headers?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the response there.

Comment: request.user returns  AnonymousUser if the request user is not authenticated

Comment: Appended my question with response info. I already authenticate user and taked token key from backend and used this key in request header

Comment: `{'Authorization': 'Token {$Token}'}` - ? Are you sure this is correct? It looks like your frontend is not providing `Authorization` header correcty. Add request headers as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not using Django-rest-framework in right way. Change your view like this

```
class CheckAuth(generics.GenericAPIView):

    def post(self, request):
        print(request.user)
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
             content = {'message': 'Authenticated'}
             return Response(content, status=200)
        else:
             content = {'message': 'Unauthenticated'}
             return Response(content, status=401)
```

You can further see Django-rest docs about views [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/).

Comment: @Farid When you are using class based views and you have defined post or get functions in view, you will not need `if request.method == 'POST` condition. I have modified code.

Answer (score 4):

For my case i had to add `@api_view(['POST'])` at the begging of the function

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def send_message(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
```

Answer (score 0):

Check settings.py where you gave authentication classes and check for the
the authentication you used on views and mentioned on settings.py are the same

In my case, I have used token authentication in views.py and given basic authentication in settings.py